# On IOS-8 Simulator, XCTest is running before app activates

Tags: ios

I have observed that on IOS-8 Simulator, XCTest runs before app gets the call "applicationDidBecomeActive). I also confirmed this by checking applicationState. However, in IOS-9, XCTests run after app has been activated, which is the desired behavior. Is this a bug on IOS-8 or is there is some setting I can do to control when XCTest should run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're observing is indeed a bug (a major bug, in my opinion) in iOS 8. It has nothing to do with XCTests, even though that's how you've encountered the issue. The problem is the *order in which events arrive* during launch in iOS 8. In other words, the issue is *not* that the app has not been activated, but that the *message* `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is arriving too late in iOS 8.

In iOS 7 and before, events (distributed between the app delegate and the root view controller) arrive in this order:

- `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- `viewDidLoad`
- `viewWillAppear:`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive:`
- `viewDidAppear:`

But iOS 8 brought with it a momentous change: the app delegate receives `applicationDidBecomeActive:` *after* the root view controller's interface has appeared and the root view controller has received `viewDidAppear:`, so that the opening sequence of events in iOS 8 is like this:

- `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- `viewDidLoad`
- `viewWillAppear:`
- `viewDidAppear:`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

This was a disaster for many of my apps, and the fact that it was reversed in iOS 9 (which works like iOS 7 and before) confirms my view that it is a bug. You'll just have to work around it somehow (or give up having your app be compatible with iOS 8).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. This helps!!

Comment: Glad to help. Good question.